# Replacing flexible.duct work on AC unit

Tags: hvac, ducts

I purchased the correct size flexible duct for the air supply, but was unaware that the return side is 2 inches bigger. Since I am unable to purchase the bigger size until next week, is it safe to run AC without return attached? The only thing I can do for now is put a small piece  of the old stuff on to keep water and dirt from getting inside.(BTW, I live in a trailer and the AC unit is outside. That's the reason for the piece to stop water from getting in. I can leave the open end under the trailer but it won't be attached to the return vent, just the AC unit.)

Comment: It wont work well at cooling since it is designed to recirculate inside air over and over cooling it more and more. This in turn draws moisture out of the air by way of condensation collecting on coil and dripping into drain. Sucking warm humid dirty air into the unit will not cool the home much and will risk crudding up the coil.

Comment: @Kris I thought as much.  I was just hoping maybe I could get by for a few days.  But I won't risk it.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Kris make an answer out of that!

Comment: I agree should be an answer @kris.+